# string($binary)

Tags: python, json, api, binary, binary-file

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как передать бинарное значение файла 'string'  через Python следуя данному body, указанному в документации Api :

```
    {
      "file": "string",
      "data": {
        "force_update": false,
        "only_available": false,
        "mark_missing_product_as": "none",
        "updated_fields": [
          "price",
          "presence"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Так же в документации указано что значение "string" является file string($binary) - xls,csv,xlsx,xml,cml документ. Со всем кодом разобрался , кроме этого момента где нужно передать string.
Вот мой код на данный момент:

```
import json
import http.client
import pprint


# API Settigs
AUTH_TOKEN = 'token'  # Your authorization token
HOST = 'my.prom.ua'  # e.g.: my.prom.ua, my.tiu.ru, my.satu.kz, my.deal.by, my.prom.md


class HTTPSError(Exception):
    pass


class EvoClientExample(object):

    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def make_request(self, method, url, body=None):
        connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(HOST)

        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.token),
                   'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        if body:
            body = json.dumps(body)

        connection.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
        response = connection.getresponse()
        if response.status != 200:
            raise HTTPSError('{}: {}'.format(response.status, response.reason ))

        response_data = response.read()
        return json.loads(response_data.decode())

    

    def import_file(self):
        url = '/api/v1/products/import_file'
        method = 'POST'
        with open('123.xlsx', mode='rb') as file: 
            file_content = file.read()
        
        body = {
            'file': file_content,
            'data':
            { 
            'force_update': 'true',
            'only_available': 'false'
             }
        }
            
        

        return self.make_request(method, url, body)

    def get_import_status(self,import_id):
        url = '/api/v1/products/import/status/{}'.format(import_id)
        method = 'GET'

        return self.make_request(method, url)


def main():
    # Initialize Client
    if not AUTH_TOKEN:
        raise Exception('Sorry, there\'s no any AUTH_TOKEN!')

    api_example = EvoClientExample(AUTH_TOKEN)
    
    importfile = api_example.import_file()
    
    print(importfile)
    
    import_id = importurl.get('id')

    import_status = api_example.get_import_status(import_id)

    print(import_status)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Programming/Desktop/prom_api 2.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Programming/Desktop/prom_api 2.py", line 69, in main
    importfile = api_example.import_file()
  File "C:/Users/Programming/Desktop/prom_api 2.py", line 53, in import_file
    return self.make_request(method, url, body)
  File "C:/Users/Programming/Desktop/prom_api 2.py", line 26, in make_request
    body = json.dumps(body)
  File "C:\Users\Programming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Programming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Programming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Programming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: это не документация, это - словарь... ссылку дайте?

Comment: @Jack_oS https://public-api.docs.prom.ua/#/ 
Раздел /products/import_url Импорт товаров

Comment: это словарь , который отправляется запросом .

Comment: https://github.com/evo-company/company-api-example/blob/master/python/api_python3-5_example.py

Вот сама документация по коду на питоне, но тут нету этого запроса

Comment: вам для prom.ua нужен api?

Comment: @ Jack_oS да, на prom.ua . Поддержка молчит и не может предоставить пример этого кода, отвечает что всё есть в документации , чего нету того нету, мол помочь уже ничем не можем.

Я использую сейчас импорт по ссылке, но там стоит большое ограничение по количеству запросов, мне нужно именно файлом передавать , уже с прошлого года этот вопрос мучаю.

Comment: попробуйте прочитать файл как бинарник: with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file: file_content = file.read() и в запросе: "file": file_content

Comment: Сделал как Вы написали.

TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable. 

Наверное неправильно отсылаю данные и теперь их нужно структурировать правильно для отправки запроса. Или я не туда копаю?

Comment: @Jack_oS добавил весь код в шапку чтоб было удобней